# SQL looping a value from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to select the last 40 rows of each `ticker` from the `Trades` table. I can do it by looping them with python. It works but there will be too many queries. I am looking for a way to do it in a single query.

So here's my sql query:

```sql
SELECT ticker, count(ticker)
FROM (SELECT * from Trades WHERE ticker = '<this_will_be_replaced>' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 40)
WHERE trade = 'buy'
GROUP BY ticker
```

Tickers:

| id | ticker |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | btcusd |
| 1 | ethusd |

Trades:

| id | ticker | amount | price | timestamp | trade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | btcusd | 0.5 | 29000 | 1681901482 | buy |
| 1 | btcusd | 0.2 | 29500 | 1681901483 | sell |
| 2 | btcusd | 0.3 | 29400 | 1681901484 | buy |
| 3 | btcusd | 0.1 | 29700 | 1681901485 | buy |

I've tried to do with inner join but it didn't work as I expected.

```sql
SELECT ticker, count(ticker)
FROM (SELECT * from Trades tr INNER JOIN Tickers tk ON tk.ticker = tr.ticker ORDER BY tr.timestamp DESC LIMIT 40)
WHERE trade = 'buy'
GROUP BY ticker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [common table expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) (or CTE) and [ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/) [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/)

```
WITH RankedTrades AS (
    SELECT
        tr.ticker,
        tr.trade,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tr.ticker ORDER BY tr.timestamp DESC) AS row_num
    FROM
        Trades tr
)
SELECT
    ticker,
    COUNT(trade) AS buy_count
FROM
    RankedTrades
WHERE
    trade = 'buy'
    AND row_num <= 40
GROUP BY
    ticker;
```